# Illustrator CS6 - Cannot scale text over ~19.5in. Instead, Illustrator moves the entire text box down and left

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, cs6, resize

I have no problems scaling text between 0in to ~19.5 inches, but above that, Illustrator moves the text box down and left (no scaling occurs). The larger my scale attempt, the further the text box is moved. For example, if I try to scale the text to 100in, it moves much further than attempting 20in. I've tried different fonts, numbers, letters, etc. and have the same issue. I'm not leaving the canvas or anything like that, there's plenty of room on the artboard. Shapes scale just fine, so converting to outlines is my current work-around. This makes editing the text a huge hassle, though, so I'd like to get this resolved. Googling around only brought up similar, but ultimately irrelevant, issues.

This problem occurred when I opened a file from another person. I feel like my settings got changed in the process, and I have no idea how to change it back. I'd like to avoid reinstalling, as I have lots of settings, addons, etc. that are exactly how I need them. I hope it's something small that I'm just overlooking, any help would be great!

Comment: You can try a selective cleanup of preferences.

Comment: Should I be looking for anything in particular? I went through Preferences a few times, and it didn't seem like anything there was going to help my issue.

Comment: Text is limited to 1296pt in Illustrator.. Is it by any chance sticking to that number? When you try and scale past that it stays at 1296pt at the bottom left of where you tried to scale to

Comment: If that's the case then there is a duplicate here: [Make font size bigger than max limit of 1296 pt in Adobe Illustrator (2015)?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/64711/52050)

Comment: (side point: there's rarely any reason to actually work at that scale anyway)

Comment: I think that's  the issue. I work at a sign shop,  so I'm the rare exception. We're making numbers for race cars today, so I guess I'll be working in outlines.

Coulda sworn I've worked even larger than that, but I've been wrong before! Thanks for the help!

Comment: work at scale! your working with vectors so it doesn't matter

Comment: I realize that. The problem came from invoicing. I knew the letters were 23.whatever" tall, but didn't know how wide that would make them (we price by square footage). When I tried to scale it up in the program, I ran into this problem. I'll just do the math next time.

Thanks again!

Comment: I agree that working that large is essentially pointless... but just to test... My copy of AICS6 won't allow type over 18inches.. so.. really.. thank your stars you have an inch-and-a-half on me :) -- for me it looks like 1296pts is the max size (18in). Never really seen this before... but also never needed type that large. -- Maybe just outline the text if you need it that big.

Comment: an alternate workflow could be to work in scale and upscale after the fact. Or you could use a transform effect to scale text beyond the limit.

Comment: Most sign shops use CorelDraw for reasons like this, and many others. I know it's quaint, old fashioned and probably wrong to recommend software here... especially something like CorelDraw. But don't knock it till you've tried it. It's old, been passed over by many hands, but gets professional stuff like packaging, signwriting, offsetting, cutouts and all manner of other real world stuff right.